# how to save a password at login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an web-api whith a login.

If I click login the browser don't ask to save the password.
How to make the browser asking?

my current HTML

```
 <div class="LogInFelder">
                <p class="standard-zeile">
                    <label class="LogIn">Mandant</label><br/><input data-bind="value: mandant" type="text" placeholder="Mandant"/>
                </p>
                <p class="standard-zeile">
                    <label class="LogIn">User</label><br/> <input data-bind="value: user" type="text" placeholder="Benutzername"/>
                </p>
                 <p class="standard-zeile">
                    <label class="LogIn">Password</label><br/><input data-bind="value: password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort"/>
                 </p>
                 <p class="standard-zeile" >
                    <a href="" data-bind="click: showDetails" class="button buttonColorGreen buttonLogIn">Anmelden</a>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers react on the `name` attribute.
Add `name="username"`, `name="password"` to the input to force this behaviour.

```
<p class="standard-zeile">
<label class="LogIn">User</label><br/>
<input name="username" data-bind="value: user" type="text" placeholder="Benutzername"/>
</p> 

<p class="standard-zeile">
<label class="LogIn">Password</label><br/>
<input name="password" data-bind="value: password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
</p>
```